# Firestore - Query and dynamicly set the Refs Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I talk about the Web here. So basicly I can make a Collection Reference like this:

`let treeRef = firebase.firestore().collection('trees')`

So now I wanna add clauses to it like `where` or `limit` so according to [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) I would write something like:

```
treeRef.where('name', '==', 'yes');
treeRef.limit(5);
```

But when I then call `treeRef.get()` the added clauses are simply ignored and it queries the whole collection not caring about the clauses added.

EDIT Example:

```
SODemo() {
  const categoryRef = this.$fireStore.collection('categories');

  categoryRef.limit(1);

  categoryRef.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    console.log(querySnapshot.size); // logs 6 in my console (collection has 6 documents)
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you show all your implementation?

Comment: @andresmijares for this minimal example I just added the .limit() but it comes down to the same result of the additional clauses not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the doc, the [`limit()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#limit) and [`where()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#where) methods "create and return a new Query", so you would need to do as follows:

```
SODemo() {
  const categoryRef = this.$fireStore.collection('categories');

  const categoryRefLimit = categoryRef.limit(1);

  categoryRefLimit.get().then(querySnapshot => {
    console.log(querySnapshot.size); // logs 6 in my console (collection has 6 documents)
  });
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks, it can be even simpler by reassigning it with itself like `let ref = ....` and then `ref = ref.limit(1)` but thanks your answer is correct.